# angular wait for subscription finishes and then return

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

In my ionic app I check if user is authenticated or not using `isAuthenticated` method. 
in `isAuthenticated()` I check if there is a valid token in storage.
if access token is expired, I refresh the token and again I return the new access token.
my problem is when I try to refresh token using `refreshToken` method, app doesn't wait until it finishes so access token will be returned null.

```
export class AuthService {
    token: JwtToken;
    isAuthenticated(): Promise<boolean> {
        return this.getToken().then(token => {
            return token != null;
        });
    }

    getToken(): Promise<JwtToken> {
        return this.storage.get('token').then(async (token: JwtToken) => {
            if (token == null) {
                return null;
            }
            const jwtHelper = new JwtHelperService();
            if (jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(token.access_token)) {
                console.log('1');
                // I need wait until the function below finished
                await this.refreshToken(token);
                console.log('3');
                // and then return refreshed access token
                return this.token;
            } else {
                return token;
            }
        });
    }

    async refreshToken(token: JwtToken) {
        console.log('2-1');
        return await this.http.post('http://api.com/auth/refresh', {refresh_token: token.refresh_token}).subscribe(async (res: JwtToken) => {
            console.log('2-2');
            this.token = res;
            await this.setToken(res);
            console.log('2-3');
            return this.token;
        });
    }
}
```

this is console output:

```
1
2-1
3
2-2
2-3
```

while I need it to be

```
1
2-1
2-2
2-3
3
```

it ignores `await refreshToken(token)` somehow...

Comment: do you try make the ``refreshToken`` function asynchrone via ``async``? ["Asynchronous functions are prefixed with the async keyword; await suspends the execution until an asynchronous function return promise is fulfilled and unwraps the value from the Promise returned"](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/async-await.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51860844/angular-5-await-not-waiting) helped me to solve my problem.

I changed `refreshToken` like this:

```
refreshToken(token: JwtToken) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        this.http.post('http://api.com/auth/refresh', {refresh_token: token.refresh_token}).subscribe(async (res: JwtToken) => {
            this.token = res;
            await this.setToken(res);
            resolve();
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the solution is to use async,await like this:
if you want to call a function refereshToken :
let result= await refereshToken(argument) ;
and the function of refereshToken's prototype you should wirte like this:
async refreshToken(token: JwtToken) {
        return this.http.post('http://api.com/auth/refresh', {refresh_token: token.refresh_token}).subscribe(async (res: JwtToken) => {
            this.token = res;
            await this.setToken(res);
            return this.token;
        });
    }